# Why is Money Necessary?

Tags: money

I've heard a lot of different economists bullet point a few main ideas as to why money is necessary. However, I'd like to get an ultimate rundown list. What are the major reasons why money is necessary for a culture to thrive?

Comment: "Money" just means "a commonly accepted medium of exchange with a commonly agreed value", or something of that ilk.  It could be walrus tusks, if the supply of tusks was stable and they were easily traded.  Without a common medium of exchange how do you maintain "trade", and without trade how does your culture "thrive"?

Comment: Historians are extremely dubious of the concept of cultures “thriving.”

Answer (score 2):

There are issues with this question as currently written.

I will attempt to offer a partial answer by responding with a different question. If money did not exist, how would governments in modern developed countries impose taxes?

Historically, rulers would impose taxes in kind: forcing peasants to serve in the army, or taking a portion of the harvest. This is not particularly easy to see how a modern government could achieve this in a politically acceptable fashion.

So if you can find a way to allow taxation without money, you have found a way for money to not be necessary in a modern developed country.

Answer (score 2):

1. Store of value.
2. Medium of exchange.
3. Unit of account.

I doubt one can easily think of a benefit offered by money not covered by one of 1-3.

I reccomend reading the [experimental work done by Camera](https://ideas.repec.org/a/aea/aejmic/v6y2014i1p290-314.html) on the emergence of money in an experimental economy. Fascinating stuff.

Edit: Whoever added the hyperlink (I think Densep) ... thanks! It inspired me to also link [Camera's website](https://www.chapman.edu/research/institutes-and-centers/economic-science-institute/about-us/gabriele-camera.aspx). If you look through his CV you will find a few other highly relevant, very interesting, and well executed papers.